# ASP.NET OWIN OAUTH2.0 with refresh token

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, oauth, owin

I am trying to use OWIN library to create OAuth2.0 authentication for my asp.net web api application. 
I added OAuthCustomRefreshTokenProvider class that inherits IAuthenticationTokenProvider, which I found online. 
Link:
https://github.com/Davidsual/WebApiBearerToken/blob/master/Davide.Trotta.WebApi.Server/SimpleRefreshTokenProvider.cs

I have realized that refreshtoken were stored in a static variable:

`private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket> _refreshTokens = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, AuthenticationTicket>();`

It seems that in production values are disappearing from this variable after few hours,even though refresh token expirydate is set to 1 year, so I am thinking about adding them to a database to keep them saved.

How should I achieve that, do you have any references or hints ?

Thank you.